# AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_get_distribution_strategy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am following an online course through linkedin regrading the Building of models through Keras.

**This is my code. (This is claimed to work)**

```py
import pandas as pd
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *

training_data_df = pd.read_csv("sales_data_training_scaled.csv")

X = training_data_df.drop('total_earnings', axis=1).values
Y = training_data_df[['total_earnings']].values

# Define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=9, activation='relu', name='layer_1'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', name='layer_2'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', name='layer_3'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', name='output_layer'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')


# Create a TensorBoard logger
logger = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
    log_dir='logs',
    write_graph=True,
    histogram_freq=5
)


# Train the model
model.fit(
    X,
    Y,
    epochs=50,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=2,
    callbacks=[logger]
)

# Load the separate test data set
test_data_df = pd.read_csv("sales_data_test_scaled.csv")

X_test = test_data_df.drop('total_earnings', axis=1).values
Y_test = test_data_df[['total_earnings']].values

test_error_rate = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("The mean squared error (MSE) for the test data set is: {}".format(test_error_rate))
```

**I get the following error when the following code was executed.**

```java
Using TensorFlow backend.
2020-01-16 13:58:14.024374: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-01-16 13:58:14.037202: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fc47b436390 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-01-16 13:58:14.037211: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/himsaragallage/Documents/Building_Deep_Learning_apps/06/model_logging final.py", line 35, in <module>
    callbacks=[logger]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1239, in fit
    validation_freq=validation_freq)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 119, in fit_loop
    callbacks.set_model(callback_model)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py", line 68, in set_model
    callback.set_model(model)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks/tensorboard_v2.py", line 116, in set_model
    super(TensorBoard, self).set_model(model)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 1532, in set_model
    self.log_dir, self.model._get_distribution_strategy())  # pylint: disable=protected-access
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_get_distribution_strategy'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**While I was trying to Debug**

I found out that this error was caused because I am trying to use a `tensorboard logger`. More accurately. When I add `callbacks=[logger]`. Without that line of code the program runs without any errors. But Tensorboard won't be used.

Please suggest me a method in which I can eliminate the error successfully run the above mentioned python script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope you are referring to this [LinkedIn Keras Course](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/building-deep-learning-applications-with-keras-2-0/visualize-the-computational-graph?).

Even I faced the Same Error when I have used **`Tensorflow Version 2.1`**. However, after downgrading the **`Tensorflow Version`** and with slight modifications in the code, I could invoke **`Tensorboard`**.

Working Code is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

training_data_df = pd.read_csv("sales_data_training_scaled.csv")

X = training_data_df.drop('total_earnings', axis=1).values
Y = training_data_df[['total_earnings']].values

# Define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=9, activation='relu', name='layer_1'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', name='layer_2'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', name='layer_3'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', name='output_layer'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# Create a TensorBoard logger
logger = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
    log_dir='logs',
    write_graph=True,
    histogram_freq=5
)

# Train the model
model.fit(
    X,
    Y,
    epochs=50,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=2,
    callbacks=[logger]
)

# Load the separate test data set
test_data_df = pd.read_csv("sales_data_test_scaled.csv")

X_test = test_data_df.drop('total_earnings', axis=1).values
Y_test = test_data_df[['total_earnings']].values

test_error_rate = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("The mean squared error (MSE) for the test data set is: {}".format(test_error_rate))
```

Answer (score 3):

You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894720/keras-and-tensorboard-attributeerror-sequential-object-has-no-attribute-g) post useful.

So instead of importing from keras (i.e.)

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

import from tensorflow:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

And this of course applies to most other imports as well.

This is just a lucky guess because I can't run your code, but hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not mixing `keras` and `tf.keras`. Those are different projects as `keras` is the original, multi-backend project and `tf.keras` is the version integrated into tensorflow. Keras will stop supporting other backends but tensorflow so it's adviced to switch to it. Check https://keras.io/#multi-backend-keras-and-tfkeras

An easy way to do that is importing keras from tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
#import keras
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Model, Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, Dropout, Input, Concatenate

print("Python: "+str(sys.version))
print("Tensorflow version: "+tf.__version__)
print("Keras version: "+keras.__version__)
```

```
Python: 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
Tensorflow version: 2.1.0
Keras version: 2.2.4-tf
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your python environment is mixing imports from `keras` and `tensorflow.keras`. Try to use **Sequential** module like this:

```
model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, the problem was tensorflows version.

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.3.0
```

fixed that