# Keras and TensorBoard - AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_get_distribution_strategy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I am using keras and trying to plot the logs using tensorboard. Bellow you can find out the error I am getting and also the list of packages versions I am using. I can not understand it is giving me the error of 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_get_distribution_strategy'.

Package:
Keras                2.3.1
Keras-Applications   1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing  1.1.0
tensorboard          2.1.0
tensorflow           2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator 2.1.0

**MODEL:**

```
model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
    #model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(len(CATEGORIES), activation='softmax'))
    model.summary()
    #opt = 'adam'       # Here we can choose a certain optimizer for our model
    opt = 'rmsprop'
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])                  # Here we choose the loss function, input our optimizer choice, and set our metrics.

    # Create a TensorBoard instance with the path to the logs directory
    tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/{}'.format(time()),
                    histogram_freq = 1,
                    embeddings_freq = 1,
                    embeddings_data = X)

    history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

**ERROR:**

````
C:\Users\Bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\tensorboard_v2.py:102: UserWarning: The TensorBoard callback does not support embeddings display when using TensorFlow 2.0. Embeddings-related arguments are ignored.
  warnings.warn('The TensorBoard callback does not support '
C:\Users\Bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\indexed_slices.py:433: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
Train on 1123 samples, validate on 125 samples
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\NN_Training.py", line 128, in <module>
    history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[tensorboard])    # Feed in the train
set for X and y and run the model!!!
  File "C:\Users\Bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1239, in fit
    validation_freq=validation_freq)
  File "C:\Users\Bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 119, in fit_loop
    callbacks.set_model(callback_model)
  File "C:\Users\Bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\callbacks.py", line 68, in set_model
    callback.set_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\Bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\tensorboard_v2.py", line 116, in set_model
    super(TensorBoard, self).set_model(model)
  File "C:\Users\Bruno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1532, in
set_model
    self.log_dir, self.model._get_distribution_strategy())  # pylint: disable=protected-access
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_get_distribution_strategy'```
````

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are mixing imports between `keras` and `tf.keras`, they are not the same library and doing this is not supported.

You should make all imports from one of the libraries, either `keras` or `tf.keras`.

Comment: I am using the following imports: from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer,
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences,
from keras.models import Sequential,
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, GlobalAveragePooling1D,
from keras.models import Model, load_model,
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard.

All are coming from keras and not mixing any libraries I guess.

Comment: @BrunoTaborda Your traceback says otherwise, as at the end is going from keras to inside tf.keras, maybe you can add a script that we can run and reproduces the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not... is there any way to just force him to use keras and not tf.keras?

Comment: @BrunoTaborda Sorry, impossible to say without actual code.

Comment: As a final solution I changed my imports from keras to tf.keras it worked.

Comment: In my case, commenting: ```from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential``` and replaced it by: ```import tensorflow``` Then to create the model: ```model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential()``` 
worked like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

It seems that your python environment is mixing imports from `keras` and `tensorflow.keras`. Try to use **Sequential** module like this:

```
model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential()
```

Or change your imports to something like

```
import tensorflow
layers = tensorflow.keras.layers
BatchNormalization = tensorflow.keras.layers.BatchNormalization
Conv2D = tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv2D
Flatten = tensorflow.keras.layers.Flatten
TensorBoard = tensorflow.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard
ModelCheckpoint = tensorflow.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint
```

...etc

Comment: I commented:
```from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential```
and replaced it by:
```import tensorflow```

Then to create my model I did just like you said:
```model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential()```

worked like a charm!